# Filtered has_many relationship form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have simple form to display a model with has_many relationship.

```
  form do |f|

    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :messages, allow_destroy: true, heading: 'Messages' do |f|
        f.input :title

      end
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

My question is: how to prefilter :messages before the from is shown?
It depends on current_admin user.

Comment: Is the model AdminUser that has many messages?

Comment: No, it's not. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeverBe!

My solution is based on creating a custom has_many relation with condition for model.
For example:

**File /app/models/key.rb**

```
class Key < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name,
                    :messages, :messages_attributes,
                    :messages_for_organization_attributes 

    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, allow_destroy: true

    has_many :messages_for_organization, class_name: 'Message', conditions: proc {"organization_id" = #{$current_admin_user.organization_id}"}
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages_for_organization, allow_destroy: true

end
```

**File /app/models/message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :title,
                    :key, :key_id
                    :organization, :organization_id

    belongs_to :key
    belongs_to :organization

end
```

**File app/admin/key.rb:**

```
controller do

    def edit
      if current_admin_user.role?('super_admin')
        @key = Key.find_by_id(params[:id])
      else
        @key = Key.joins('LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.key_id = key.id').where(id: params[:id]).first
      end
      $current_admin_user = current_admin_user # Important assignment to get access current_admin_user in Key model class

      edit!
    end

end


form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs do
        if current_admin_user.role?('super_admin')
            f.has_many :messages, allow_destroy: true, heading: 'Messages' do |f|
                f.input :title
            end
        else
            f.has_many :messages_for_organization, allow_destroy: true, heading: 'Messages' do |f|
                f.input :title
            end
        end
    end

    f.actions
end
```